# asp.net dropdownlist not showing DataTextField if there is a DataTextValueField too

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datatextfield

I have a `DataValueField` and a `DataTextField` in my `DropDownList`. The data is from a `DataSet` and I want the `dropdownlist` to show the text field of my `Dataset` as preselected text. The `Dataset` is filled with data from a `mysql table`, containing "`id`" and "`text`". The `DropDownList` code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataValueField="id" 
DataTextField="text" ID="statusList" CssClass="viewItemRight" 
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

If there is no `DataValueField`-Tag the `DropDownList` shows correctly the text-value from my `DataSet` as preselected text in my `DropDownList`. But if I add the `DataValueField` the `DataTextField` doesnt showing any preselected Text in the `DropDownList`.

The code for the data is:

```
//load statusList
            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM statuslist WHERE active = '1' ORDER BY sorting ASC";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            statusList.DataSource = ds;
            statusList.DataBind();
            statusList.Items.Insert(0, " ");
```

How can I use both, the `DataValueField` and the `DataTextField`?

Comment: from where u r populating this dropdown ..so its code....if u populating from database than...show ur database schema..

Comment: code added but I think the code is not the problem

Comment: its bcz u insert " " item at 0 index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

Code:

```
DataTable dt = populatedd();
   statusList.DataSource = dt;
   statusList.DataTextField = "name";
   statusList.DataValueField = "id";
   statusList.DataBind();

    public DataTable populatedd()
    {
        string myQuery = "select id,name from yourtable order by name";
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(myQuery, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Markup

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="statusList" CssClass="viewItemRight" 
AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```